# Connecting Gitlab database with Pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, psql, pgadmin

How to connect my Gitlab database (using postgresql) to Pgadmin ? I can access the database from terminal using >> sudo gitlab-rails db . The \l command on terminal shows gitlab as ownerand a couple of other databases with gitlab-rails as owner. I'm new to handling databases and am trying to copy the tables from mysql from gitlab on another server using mysqlworkbench to the gitlab on my server manually.

Comment: Please tag correctly. MySQL and Postgres are not the same thing.

Comment: ya, i'm trying to copy tables from mysql manually as i mentioned, so tagged it. Wondering if that's possible

Comment: It could be done through a language like PHP - read from MySQL and INSERT into postgres. Using a dump probably won't work due to command and syntax differences.

Comment: Why you want to do this manually? There is an automatic procedure for this.

Comment: Can you please tell how ?@secustor. I just have a mysql gitlabhq_production

Answer (score 0):

**MANUAL**

You can use the MySQL to Postgresql exporter. This tool is also used in Gitlab itself to handle databases migrations between this two types.

https://github.com/gitlabhq/mysql-postgresql-converter

**AUTOMATED**

See the official migration guide:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/mysql_to_postgresql.md

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's if i have access to the gitlab database of other computer. I just have a dump and even more the mysql and psql tables are not same in the different version of gitlab. So doing it manually is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Omnibus Docker Image and you want to access the PostgreSQL Database via TCP, do the following.

Change these lines in `gitlab.rb`:

---

```
postgresql['listen_address'] = '*'
postgresql['port'] = 5432
```

> Enter your IP Range in CIDR notation or use this `['0.0.0.0/0']` if you don't care  about security
>   
> Sample: `['192.168.0.0/16', '127.0.0.1/24']`

```
postgresql['md5_auth_cidr_addresses'] = []
```

> Then open a bash instance inside the docker container and generate a hash with
>
> `gitlab-ctl pg-password-md5 gitlab`

```
postgresql['sql_user_password'] = 'Replace_with_generated_hash'
```

---

Now you can expose port 5432 and connect with for example pgAdmin, User `gitlab` and your configured password.